# How to debug Sconstruct script with Pycharm?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, scons

I want to setup Pycharm so I can use it to dive into my Sconstruct scrip, and also into python scripts used by SConstruct. Is there any way to setup Pycharm for that purpose?

If there is a bit detailed explanation hot to accomplish that would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Milos

Answer (score 0):

There's no fully satisfactory way: that would require PyCharm knowledge of the SCons API, which is a requested feature (but not requested enough to trigger any action yet, I've heard it requires far more votes than this):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10591

You can make things better by teaching PyCharm that SConstruct and SConscript are Python files, or by naming your script files with a .py suffix (SCons will automatically recognize several synonyms for SConstruct, including SConstruct.py). At least then normal Python stuff will work, but it won't know about the SCons functions - maybe if you include a local-install copy of scons in your project tree, I've never explicitly tried that.